# tiny-dnn Illegal instruction

Tags: c++, c, tiny-dnn

I was using tiny-dnn recently, however when I try to use AVX/AVX2 instructions to train example_minist_train, e.g. set(USE_AVX ON) , I got Illegal instruction (core dumped) error. I try to debug in Clion-IDE, I got the error in gdb :
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x0000000000448b66 in tiny_dnn::weight_init::xavier::fill(std::vector >*, unsigned long, unsigned long) ()

I use Ubuntu 14.04 STL 64bit system, and the information of my cpu like this :

> processor : 31
>
> vendor_id : GenuineIntel
>
> cpu family : 6
>
> model : 62
>
> model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz
>
> stepping : 4
>
> microcode : 0x428
>
> cpu MHz : 2600.101
>
> cache size : 20480 KB
>
> physical id : 1
>
> siblings : 16
>
> core id : 7
>
> cpu cores : 8
>
> apicid : 47
>
> initial apicid : 47
>
> fpu : yes
>
> fpu_exception : yes
>
> cpuid level : 13
>
> wp : yes
>
> flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov
>   pat pse36  clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx
>   pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl
>   xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor
>   ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2
>   x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida
>   arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase
>   smep erms xsaveopt
>
> bugs :
>
> bogomips : 5201.86
>
> clflush size : 64
>
> cache_alignment : 64
>
> address sizes : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
>
> power management:

when I use SSE, e.g. set(USE_SSE ON) and set(USE_AVX OFF), set(USE_AVX2 OFF), the program will run normly, how can I fix this problem? thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that CPU supports `AVX2` instruction set? it looks like it supports `AVX` though can you try setting just `AVX2` off as you have v2 version of that CPU it doesn't appear to support `AVX2` instruction set: http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Xeon-E5-2650-v3-vs-Intel-Xeon-E5-2650-v2

Comment: The flags you have shown do not include AVX2 only AVX. If `set(USE_AVX_ON)` is causing problems then this flag is inaccurate & is using AVX2 instructions